# Importing database with unknown character set, which collation to use?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqlimport

I was given a dump from a database in tab delimitered format that I'm trying to import. Unfortunately I can't get the `CREATE TABLE` query so I'm trying to guess what they used.

I've tried importing with various utf8 and latin1 collation's but they all give me these warnings

```
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE1\x9A Tom...' for column 'username' at row 28907
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE1n Mar...' for column 'username' at row 29105
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE1n' for column 'username' at row 29192
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE1r G\xE9z...' for column 'username' at row 29313
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE7alves' for column 'username' at row 29487
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xF6res' for column 'username' at row 29728
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xFE\xF3rsso...' for column 'username' at row 29842
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xF6l' for column 'username' at row 30117
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xF3hann ...' for column 'username' at row 30310
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xFCchner' for column 'username' at row 30432
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD6sterr...' for column 'username' at row 30486
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xFCrgenK...' for column 'username' at row 30795
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE1n Les...' for column 'username' at row 30846
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE0tz \xD1\xD6...' for column 'username' at row 31002
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE9n Fer...' for column 'username' at row 31015
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE4cker' for column 'username' at row 31048
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xDFe' for column 'username' at row 31505
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE1nchez...' for column 'username' at row 31762
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\x9A Stre...' for column 'username' at row 32144
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\x9A Stre...' for column 'username' at row 32145
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xF6rk' for column 'username' at row 32309
```

Another table

```
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x91-esz...' for column 'clear' at row 180175
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x91dies...' for column 'clear' at row 180181
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xB04510...' for column 'clear' at row 324698
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x9Fem' for column 'clear' at row 332177
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x91' for column 'clear' at row 333689
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x91' for column 'clear' at row 420229
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\xBAdzio...' for column 'clear' at row 492435
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD1\x8A\xD0\xB9\xD1\x8C' for column 'clear' at row 512071
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x91_000...' for column 'clear' at row 516010
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x84' for column 'clear' at row 518718
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x82gorz...' for column 'clear' at row 518879
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x82!' for column 'clear' at row 518984
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE4\xB8\xAD\xE5\x9B\xBD' for column 'clear' at row 578301
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x9Fifre...' for column 'clear' at row 622762
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x9B\xC4\x87' for column 'clear' at row 651931
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xB8\xB4\xE0\xB8\x99...' for column 'clear' at row 653857
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xB9\x81\xE0\xB9\x89...' for column 'clear' at row 655241
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xBA\xD0\xB0\xD0\xBA...' for column 'clear' at row 696299
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x95\xD0\xBA\xD0\xB0...' for column 'clear' at row 696338
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x9F\xD1\x80\xD0\xB8...' for column 'clear' at row 696389
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD1\x85\xD0\xB5\xD1\x80...' for column 'clear' at row 696558
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD1\x80\xD0\xB5\xD0\xB3...' for column 'clear' at row 696629
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD1\x85\xD1\x83\xD0\xB9...' for column 'clear' at row 696637
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xBF\xD0\xBE\xD1\x80...' for column 'clear' at row 697145
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xB2\xD0\xB8\xD1\x82...' for column 'clear' at row 697595
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xA0\xC2\xB1\xD0\xA0...' for column 'clear' at row 697771
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x91\xD0\xBB\xD0\xB0...' for column 'clear' at row 698058
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xDF\xA7' for column 'clear' at row 705955
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xDF\xB4' for column 'clear' at row 705965
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xDF\x80' for column 'clear' at row 705972
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xDC\xA7' for column 'clear' at row 707670
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xDC\xB4' for column 'clear' at row 707680
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xDC\x80' for column 'clear' at row 707687
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xB1\xD1\x83\xD1\x80...' for column 'clear' at row 772209
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD9\x87\xD9\x88\xD9\x84...' for column 'clear' at row 773723
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD9\x86\xD8\xAF\xD9\x8A...' for column 'clear' at row 773754
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x97' for column 'clear' at row 800748
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x9Blina' for column 'clear' at row 800966
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x97' for column 'clear' at row 801332
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xBC\xD0\xBE\xD0\xBE...' for column 'clear' at row 801512
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\xBCen' for column 'clear' at row 801552
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC4\xB1' for column 'clear' at row 826638
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x9B\xC5\xA1\xC4\x8D...' for column 'clear' at row 848786
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x8Dky' for column 'clear' at row 931036
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x9B\xC5\xA1na' for column 'clear' at row 931643
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x8Dko' for column 'clear' at row 932973
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC4\xBE' for column 'clear' at row 933156
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x9B\xC5\xA1\xC4\x8D...' for column 'clear' at row 933795
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x97\x8F\xE2\x97\x8F...' for column 'clear' at row 952359
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x97\x8F\xE2\x97\x8F...' for column 'clear' at row 952559
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xB9\xD1\x8B\xD0\xB1' for column 'clear' at row 1000672
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x9B' for column 'clear' at row 1046203
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\xBCeron...' for column 'clear' at row 1075021
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC4\xB1n' for column 'clear' at row 1077277
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x9Bko12...' for column 'clear' at row 1078692
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x9B444' for column 'clear' at row 1078953
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC4\xB1ktan' for column 'clear' at row 1082672
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x82ar\xC3\xB3...' for column 'clear' at row 1084747
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x82czy\xC5...' for column 'clear' at row 1085133
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x84stwo...' for column 'clear' at row 1086168
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x82abym...' for column 'clear' at row 1086203
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x97\x8F\xE2\x97\x8F...' for column 'clear' at row 1086486
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x97\x8F\xE2\x97\x8F...' for column 'clear' at row 1086506
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x97\x8F\xE2\x97\x8F...' for column 'clear' at row 1086508
```

I can't seem to figure out what collation they used and am out of ideas. I'm not a character encoding expert either which makes things even more difficult. Other questions have mentioned using some of the Microsoft encodings that store things weird but without warnings. However I'm nervous about doing this since its a username column and being stored wrong or displayed weird isn't an option. Same for the 'clear' column

Any idea's?

Comment: Find out the original encoding of your source data. Not much else you can do aside from that.

Comment: @newtover `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could not sovle your problem using Pelshoff suggestion, I think you can use `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci` for this case. These collations are most popular ...

Comment: Well `utf8_unicode_ci` fixed the clear column warnings, but for some reason it didn't fix the username column

Comment: Still got Incorrect String Value warnings. Tried `utf8_general_ci`, `utf8_unicode_ci`, `utf8_bin`, and `latin1_swedish_ci`

Comment: Umm..., it's hard to find out what's the problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try and find out the character encoding with a function such as mb_detect_encoding. Other than that, good luck!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Answer (score 0):

well if you dont know what country it came from or even the original purpose of it... it could also itself BE CORRUPTED. i mean if it has many many columns that are taking without error i would put it first into a spreadsheet or try NOTETAB which handles large! text files and give it a lookover.

Comment: I doubt its corrupted. With it coming from a ZIP file which IIRC has some kind of built in integrity checking and with ~2.5 million rows I would expect more than 20 warnings about encoding issues